# connecting to host on a specific port with bluetooth socket on Android

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, port, host

I have a hard time getting started with a simple bluetooth example which has to connect to a host specified by "192.168.0.1" on a port 123.

All samples that I found initiate a connection given a MAC address or a UUID that looks very different.

Is there a simple sample somewhere which shows this kind of connection - or do I miss something trivial here?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"192.168.0.1" port 123 are addresses for IP.  Bluetooth doesn't use IP, so those numbers are meaningless for a BT connection.  Bluetooth hardware devices are identified by a unique 48-bit address.  Bluetooth protocol software services are identified by UUIDs.

Comment: ok, I thought one could also use bluetooth for IP connections... Many thanks for clearing this up!

Comment: You can tunnel IP over Bluetooth, but this is done at the application layer by software supporting the Dial Up Networking (DUN) profile.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile#Dial-up_Networking_Profile_.28DUN.29